# Will sub folder app use main site timeout setting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I plan to have another web app in a sub folder.  It will be accessed as www.site.com/subapp.  Users will always access it from the main web app (www.site.com).  Once a user lands on the sub web app, how does timing out work?  I don't want them to go back to the main app only to find that it has timed out.  The main app should not time out while the user is on the sub app.

Comment: I would be more concerned about having your session cookie overwritten.

Comment: What would happen in that case?

Comment: Your first session might get invalidated (and thus logged out), you can specify different cookie names for different apps, but when you're browsing the sub app, the main app has no knowledge of this and will eventually time out anyway.

Comment: Ok.  What would be a technique to use so the main app doesn't timeout in this case?  How is that usually done?

Comment: If it's within the same hostname, you could have your subapp periodically make an ajax call to the main app to keep it alive.  Though your main app and sub app would be adjacent, not parent / child.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is any benefit to using a handler vs ajax call in this case?